# Delete from collection if empty

Tags: php, laravel

How to delete the item when products[] is empty?

This is how I get it from the database:

```
$orders = Order::with(['order_details.products' => function($q) use ($place) {
    $categories = Categorie::where('place', $place)->get();
    $validCategories = [];
    foreach ($categories as $categorie){
      array_push($validCategories, $categorie->id);
    }
    $q->where('products.categorie_id', '=', $validCategories);
}])->get();
```

and this is the result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOSnI.png)

But I only want the items if products[] is not empty. How can I do that?

for example here: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulwkF.png) 
Here are the products empty but now I want to remove all this data.

Comment: if what `products` is empty? there is no `products` variable here ... and how to delete what item?

Comment: Products are in the result, and if that is empty I want to remove/ delete all the other data in that collection item. For example here                                            {
"order_id": 13,
"product_id": 1,
"quantity": 1,
"created_at": "2019-12-29 19:12:10",
"updated_at": "2019-12-29 19:12:10",
"products": []
}, I want to delete all of this

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to filter the eager load using `with` with a callback and using a `whereHas` with the same callback to remove the unneeded `order_details`.

Try something like this:

```
$catIds = Categorie::where('place', $place)->pluck('id');

$orders = Order::with(['order_details' => function ($q) use ($catIds) {
    $q->whereHas(['products' => $func = function ($q) use ($catIds) {
        $q->whereIn('categorie_id', $catIds)
    })->with(['products' => $func]);
}])->get();
```

If not you can iterate through your collection and remove the unneeded records.